# How to make a file accessible only by a certain program?

Tags: windows, encryption

If I had a file(s) stored in, for example:

C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Example\Example

Would it be possible to make that file be unable to be opened by a user manually going through the files but able to be opened by, for example, a python program using the f=open("file.txt", "r") etcetera etcetera code?

Is it also possible to make a program encrypted and require a password to access without programming something yourself- is there a built in feature of windows that can do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [How do I password protect my files and folders in Windows?](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000705.htm)

Comment: [How to Password Protect Files and Folders With Encryption](https://www.howtogeek.com/170352/how-to-password-protect-files-and-folders-with-encryption/)

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions for the first question?

Comment: That's not possible without running the python program as a different user.

Comment: Re the first question:  for most users, it'd be enough to make the file hidden and/or a system file. Under Windows default settings, the user would never see the file.  This is by no means a perfect solution, but would work most of the time.  Whether it's adequate will depend on how secure you need to make the file.  Another approach would be to encrypt the text file and have the python routine that opens the file also decrypt it.

Comment: The final point is not a bad idea. For the first idea how would I do that and would it mean I cannot view the file in the folder but can open it from a program because that would be perfect?